# How to add click event to column header in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have a requirement of selecting the whole column when the column header is clicked. I am unable to find any solution for this as there is no 'click' event for columns in ag-grid. Only events that I could find were to *'sort'* or *'pin'* columns. **I also want to have column data on click so that I can perform other task based on which column was selected.** Attaching screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could select the column cell, with document.querySelector and then on the ngAfterViewInit() method, add an eventListener for the click. But without knowing if  your table generates unique identifiers for the table, I could not provide any other ideas. On the documentation theres this attribute col-id... Can you search for it?

Comment: Hey @RafaeldeCastro, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it in the same way as you suggested. I was able to extract col-id on click on column header cells. After that I was able to filter and update row data style based on col-id. Will write a detailed answer for this and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by extracting col-id attribute from all the divs having class name **'ag-header-cell'**.

```
this.colElements = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-cell') as HTMLCollectionOf<
    HTMLElement
  >
);
```

And then adding click event listener on each item found. This will get us the col-id attribute when we click on column header.

```
this.colElements.forEach((elem, index) => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    attribute = elem.getAttribute('col-id');
    //you can add you custom styling based on selected index here
  });
});
```

Next in the **'columnDefs'** array we add custom **'cellStyle'** by filtering cell items based on col-id we extracted.

```
columnDefs: [
      {
        headerName: 'State',
        field: 'dynamic',
        cellStyle: (params) => {
          if (params.colDef.field === this.selectedColId) {
            return { color: '#001D6D', backgroundColor: '#F3F7FF' };
          }
          return null;
        },
      },
    ],
```

Finally on every click event of event listener, we add **'redrawRow'** function.

```
columnSelected(colId) {
  this.gridOptions.api.redrawRows();
}
```

Comment: That only works if your grid entirely fits in the parent div and does not have horizontal slider. Coulmns that are not in the view will be ignored. Worse yet once a column scrolls out if the view it looses the onclick handler